# Web server and Reverse Proxy in the same port nginx

Tags: nginx, webserver, reverse-proxy

I need to have a web server and a reverse proxy in the same domain (and the same port) to solve some cors domain issues, now I have both servers in separate ports, how can I have both in the same port and in the same domain.

This is my configuration:

```
#:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  root /var/www/my-page/;
  index index.html;
  ssl_certificate /home/certs/cert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/certs/cert.key;
  server_name myserver.com;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    root /var/www/my-page/;
  }
}
#::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
server {
    listen 5601 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate /home/certs/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/certs/cert.key;
    server_name myserver.com;
    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic mybase64";
        access_log /var/log/nginx/kibana.access.log;
        proxy_pass https://mywebsitepass.com;
    }
}
```